# sam package too large when deploying custom runtime lambda

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

So I replicated [this project](https://github.com/aws-samples/sessions-with-aws-sam/tree/master/swift-custom-runtime) which uses **swift** as custom lambda runtime using a makefile as build method.

Now I created a AWS CodePipeline that packages my project using CodeBuild using `sam package` and finally deploys it via CloudFormation.

The `codeUri` of my lambda is set at the root folder like you see in the repo I linked above. I think that is how it should as I saw that as well in the sam documentation under the custom runtime section. The problem with that is that `sam package` packages my entire project and lambda is complaining at deploy time that the zip is too large.

How would I set up the `makefile` as well as the `template.yml` so that `sam package` only packages my lambdas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work with a slightly different strategy. This is for anyone who found them selfs in the same situation.

##### 1. Don't use sam to build your lambda functions.

I am running a variety on shell scripts to initiate the `swift build` in the `/scripts` folder.

```
.
├── Package.resolved
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
├── Sources
│   └── YourFirstLambda
│       ├── main.swift
│       └── requirements.txt
├── buildspec.yml
├── samconfig.toml
├── scripts
│   ├── build-and-package-all.sh
│   ├── build-and-package.sh
│   └── package.sh
└── template.yml
```

`build-and-package-all.sh`
**Start this shell script from inside the `scripts` folder**. You can change this behavior if you change all the dir paths.

This initiate the `build-and-packange.sh` script for each function defined in the array `lambdas`.

```sh
declare -a lambdas=("YourFirstLambda" "YourSeconLambda")
workspace="$(pwd)/.."

## now loop through the above array

if [ -f /.dockerenv ]; then
    # This is executed if run inside docker
    echo "I'm inside matrix ;(";
    for lambda in "${lambdas[@]}"
        do 
            # Second parameter is wheather we are inside a docker container or not
            ./build-and-package.sh $lambda "FALSE"
    done
else
    echo "I'm living in real world!";
    for lambda in "${lambdas[@]}"
        do
            # Second parameter is wheather we are inside a docker container or not
            ./build-and-package.sh $lambda "TRUE"
    done
fi
```

`build-and-package.sh`

This script runs

- `swift build` **and**
- package.sh

on a docker container if the `build-and-package-all.sh` is executed on a bare metal machine. This is useful because you can run this on a machine that does not have swift installed.

On the other hand we will run `swift build` on bare metal if we are already in a docker container. This might be the case like it was for me when you want to build you functions using AWS CodeBuild. They also use a docker container so there is no need to start a docker container inside a docker container.

```sh
set -eu

executable=$1
isBareMetal=$2
workspace="$(pwd)/.."
if [ $isBareMetal == "TRUE" ]; then
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
       echo "building \"$executable\" lambda"
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
              docker run --rm -v "$workspace":/workspace -w /workspace/ codebuild-swift \
                     bash -cl "swift build --product $executable -c release"
       echo "done"

       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
       echo "packaging \"$executable\" lambda"
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
              docker run --rm -v "$workspace":/workspace -w /workspace/ codebuild-swift \
                     bash -cl "sh scripts/package.sh $executable"
       echo "done"
else
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
       echo "building \"$executable\" lambda"
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
              cd $workspace
              swift build --product $executable -c release  
       echo "done"

       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
       echo "packaging \"$executable\" lambda"
       echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
              sh $workspace/scripts/package.sh $executable
       echo "done"
fi
```

Finally we package the swift lambda to a .zip.
`package.sh`

```sh
set -eu
executable=$1
target=".build/lambda/$executable"
rm -rf "$target"
mkdir -p "$target"
cp ".build/release/$executable" "$target/"
# add the target deps based on ldd
ldd ".build/release/$executable" | grep swift | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs cp -Lv -t "$target"
cd "$target"
ln -s "$executable" "bootstrap"
zip --symlinks lambda.zip *
```

##### 2. Tell sam where to find the zipped lambda

In the `template.yml` you should have a section that describes your lambda like so:

```yaml
...
YourLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Timeout: 5
      Handler: Provided
      Runtime: provided
      MemorySize: 128
      Description: Test Lambda
      Role: !GetAtt Role.Arn
      CodeUri: .build/lambda/YourLambdaFunction/lambda.zip
...
```

---

You can now use `sam build`, `sam deploy` or `sam package`. Sam will only upload the zipped lambda which should be in the 30Mb range. Probably less for you if you do not have many dependencies.

###### Side note.

You will need a docker container that has swift installed. My docker image is tagged `codebuild-swift` and uses the following docker file. If you name your docker image differently you then have to update the `build-and-package.sh`:

```
FROM swift:5.2-amazonlinux2

RUN yum -y install \
    git \
    libuuid-devel \
    libicu-devel \
    libedit-devel \
    libxml2-devel \
    sqlite-devel \
    python-devel \
    ncurses-devel \
    curl-devel \
    openssl-devel \
    tzdata \
    libtool \
    gcc-c++ \
    jq \
    tar \
    zip \
    glibc-static
```

The shell scripts above are all based from this site:
[Getting started with sift AWS Lambda runtime](https://fabianfett.de/getting-started-with-swift-aws-lambda-runtime)